# Prove for all p > 1, $x * y = (p + 1)^{-2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

We have 2 equations with 3 unknowns x, y and Real parameter p:

1. \begin{equation*}
     px + y = 1
   \end{equation*}
2. \begin{equation*}x + py = 1\end{equation*}

How to prove for all p > 1,  $x * y = (p + 1)^{-2}$

Comment: If we add the equations, we get $(p+1)(x+y) = 2$. If we subtract, we get $(p-1)(x-y)=0$. Since $p\neq1$, this implies $x-y=0\to x=y$. So, that implies our first equation becomes $(p+1)x=1$. Squaring, we get $(p+1)^2x^2=1\to x^2=\frac1{(p+1)^2}$. So, $$xy=\frac1{(p+1)^2}$$ Note that the condition that we needed for $p$ was simply $p\neq\pm1$, rather than $p>1$.

Comment: You should make this an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A naive approach.

From the first,
$y = 1-px$.

Substituting in the second,
$1
=x+py
=x+p(1-px)
=x+p-p^2x
=x(1-p^2)+p
$
or
$x
=\dfrac{1-p}{1-p^2}
$.

If $p \ne 1$,
$x
=\dfrac1{1+p}
$.
Then
$y
=1-px
=1-\dfrac{p}{1+p}
=\dfrac{1+p-p}{1+p}
=\dfrac1{1+p}
=x
$
so
$xy
=\dfrac1{(1+p)^2}
$.

Comment: Very nice, thx!